# static_cast to the base of base class with protected inheritance

Tags: c++

I don't quite understand why below code is not legal.

```
struct A {
    int a;
};

struct B : protected A {
    int b;
};

struct C : B {
    int c;
} tc;

const A &ra = static_cast<A &>(tc);
```

Could someone help to explain it? Thank you very much.

Comment: q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class#Protected_inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `public`, `protected` and `private` specifiers let access in different-wide areas. You can access `protected` members only in your class functions or its heirs.

For example that code works:

```cpp
    struct A {
        int a;
    };
    
    struct B : protected A {
        int b;
    };
    
    struct C : /*implicit `public` because C is struct but not class*/ B {
        int c;
        
        void foo(C &tc)
        {
            const A &ra = static_cast<A &>(tc);
            // Because `foo` can access to A instead of outside code like yours.
        }
    };
```

Comment: "*implicit `public` because C is struct but not class*/" is a tiny bit wrong. `C` is a class. `struct` and `class` are just two keywords to define a class. Though, yes, because you used `struct` the class default visibility is public

Comment: So, you mean, it's not because it's to cast C to A (skip B), just because it's outside of C, correct?

Comment: The cast must be inside of struct C visability to be correct. If inheritance A -> B was `public` then we could cast outside. Lasty, if inheritance A -> B was `private` then cast C -> A might be accessed in B visibility only.

Comment: Are the below two equivalent for this case?  static_cast<A&>(static_cast<B&>(tc))  and  static_cast<A&>(tc)

Comment: Yes, even if you have reloaded the cast operator С->A.  
When you have `tc` object with one field 'c', it has technically a more field of its parent B type which also has `b` and a field of its parent A type which eventually has one 'a'. When you do `static_cast`, you just uses the `lvalue` reference (in our case) to the particular parent.

Comment: OK, so you were saying it's safe to static_cast to the parent's parent, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Much like protected members, the inheritance is only known to `B` and its descendants, not to anyone else.
If this were legal, protected inheritance would be pretty pointless since anyone could just cast it away.